# what event is intended for clicking the whole row in datagridview

Tags: datagridview

I would like to know what event should I use in order to click the whole row of datagridview and provide an action after clicking. I already use the cellcontentclick but only a specific cell lets an action be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are talking about a `WinForms` `DataGridView` control.

You need to handle the `RowStateChanged` event. The `DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs` object **`e`** contains a `StateChanged` property, and you need to check if the state is `Selected`. As a slight warning, the value will be returned as `Selected` both when a row has become selected and become unselected, so you may need some additional logic to check if `e.Row` is selected or not depending on your scenario.